# Unable to set social icons using Advance Portfolio Theme

Tags: themes, social-connect

I am working on a live project and installed a theme named advance portfolio. In customization, I am trying to set the social icon button but I am unable to see it anywhere on the page.

[image]

Note: I want to add the buttons on the navigation/top menu bar.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: At first glance from the theme source code those links only appear on the front page (page-template/custom-front-page.php). You could copy the code from there into the header yourself?

Comment: @Rup I didn't get you

Comment: OK, if you look at the image on the [theme page on wordpress.org](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/themes/advance-portfolio/) you can see the social links are shown underneath the title (the 'Lorem ipsum elit, dolor sit amet') on the theme's front page. That's where they appear on this theme. If you want them in the navigation / top menu then you'll have to change the code to add them there too.

Comment: You can't do that with configuration only I don't think, or at least I can't see how. If you ask the theme authors they might be able to tell you?